# Start bash process with changed prompt PS1

Tags: bash, shell

How do I start a bash subprocess with a changed prompt. Using env does not work:

```
env PS1="change >" bash --login
```

does not work. The result should be the same as using export after the process is started:

```
$ export PS1="change >"
change >
```

`~/.bashrc` has to be evaluated as usual.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as per the new on-topic rules, so it belongs on Unix and Linux SE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another solution would be:

```
bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'PS1="change > "')
```

This keeps the aliases and co by executing an "extended" version of the user's startup file.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior is normal: with `--login`, bash will read your initialization files and these redefine `PS1`.

You may try:

```
(source .bashrc; env PS1="change >" bash --norc)
```

This works for me:

```
fg@erwin ~ $ grep FOO ~/.bashrc
export FOO=bar
fg@erwin ~ $ (source ~/.bashrc; env PS1="change> " bash --norc)
change> echo $FOO
bar
```

But it only works *because .bashrc doesn't source any file which redefine PS1*.

Comment: Should have added that to the fineprint. I have to run .bashrc.

Comment: Can you paste it? If it sources files which redefine PS1, you are pretty much doomed...

Answer (score 5):

Try `bash --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='somethingelse>'")`. This uses process substitution to create a "file" which contains the PS1 setting and gives that to bash. Your current shell should support this kind of substitution (bash and zsh do).

Comment: Thank you. This was the ticket for me.
I've got a bunch of things in .bashrc, .profile, and other scripts that interfered.